# re-formating HD

Tags: system-installation

I have made a mess out of the HD in my netbook, i need to re-format the entire drive which has no date except different versions of Ubuntu. How can i re-format the drive using flash drives or an external read only CD/DVD reader and what command lines need to be used and what is the procedure in particular to do so please. i'm not computer literate by the way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a Ubuntu installation CD, then all you need to do is boot up and run `sudo gparted` from the terminal.  From there, you can delete, add, or resize existing partitions.

If you want to start everything over, including removing windows, go through each partition, right-click, then **Delete**.  Click the Check mark [Apply all operations] to apply the changes immediately.

Then, if you want Windows, create a new partition for it with the appropriate size, make it NTFS.  Then make a partition for Linux, EXT4, probably nearly the rest of your drive.  You probably want to have a swap partition for hibernating.  Make it a little higher than your ram size [if 2GB ram, make it slightly over 2GB, maybe 2050MB].